# react-hook-form with react-redux-firebase not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase, redux, react-hooks

Not sure if this is a bug or not, but I'm trying it here. I'm trying to use `react-hook-form` with `react-redux-firebase`, but I cannot get it working. I made a simple example which uses `react-redux-firebase` to initialize `Firebase` and then created a form component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function Form() {
  const [register, submit] = useForm();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Type in your text</h1>
      <form>
        <input ref={register} type="text" required></input>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

As soon as I include the line with `useForm`, the page immediately crashes with "TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance".

How can I solve this? The complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/ppotter100/react-redux-firebase-useform):

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into the docs of `react-hook-form` again. Looks like you'll be destructuring an object `{}`, not array `[]`.

Try changing this line:

```
const [register, submit] = useForm();
```

to:

```
const {register, submit} = useForm();
```